# wondering how the function work step by step

Tags: python

```
def main():
    move_discs(3,1,3,2)
    
def move_discs(num, from_peg, to_peg, temp_peg):
    if num > 0:
     move_discs(num-1, from_peg, temp_peg, to_peg)
     print(num,'Move a disc from peg', from_peg, 'to peg', to_peg)
     move_discs(num-1, temp_peg, from_peg, to_peg)

main()
```

i wrote the code from the textbook that i am currently learning about the recursion, this function returned the output:

```
1 Move a disc from peg 1 to peg 3
2 Move a disc from peg 1 to peg 2
1 Move a disc from peg 3 to peg 1
3 Move a disc from peg 1 to peg 3
1 Move a disc from peg 2 to peg 3
2 Move a disc from peg 2 to peg 1
1 Move a disc from peg 3 to peg 2
```

i am very confusing how this function can returned this such output and with just a small changed? can anyone explain it for me about every single steps that the function executed? i will be very appreciated.
ps: the function is just displaying a solution for the Tower of Hanoi game.
[image]

Comment: This is an example of a recursive function: a function which calls itself. Notice the `base case`, which is when `n <= 0`, where the function *doesn't* call itself. You should do some research on this topic.

Comment: https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/Recursion/TowerofHanoi.html

Answer (score 0):

This an example [Tower of Hanoi.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) move_discs is an example [recursive function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion), which calls itself while num > 0. You should also check The Tower of Hanoi program [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python-program-for-tower-of-hanoi).